# Auth0 email magic link `Error: Invalid state` for vue

Tags: vue.js, auth0, password-less

#### Checklist

- The issue can be reproduced in the [auth0-vue sample app](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/tree/master/01-Login) (or N/A).
- I have looked into the [Readme](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue#readme), [Examples](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md), and [FAQ](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/blob/main/FAQ.md) and have not found a suitable solution or answer.
- I have looked into the [API documentation](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-vue/) and have not found a suitable solution or answer.
- I have searched the [issues](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/issues) and have not found a suitable solution or answer.
- I have searched the [Auth0 Community](https://community.auth0.com) forums and have not found a suitable solution or answer.
- I agree to the terms within the [Auth0 Code of Conduct](https://github.com/auth0/open-source-template/blob/master/CODE-OF-CONDUCT.md).

#### Description

Generated magiclink using `passwordlessMethod: 'link'` got in my email corrctly but clicking link shows:
[image]

But if I click login button once again it works fine!

#### Reproduction

1. Click login button
2. Provide email
3. Check mail for the magic link
4. Click on the link (Shows: `Error: Invalid state`)
5. Click again login button (works fine for the 2nd time)

#### auth0-vue version

2.2.0

#### Vue version

3.3.4

#### Which browsers have you tested in?

Chrome

[Auth0 GitHub issue](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/issues/249)

I've searched but found no solution from [auth0/docs/spa/vuejs](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/interactive). And found same issue [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/invalid-state-error-in-vue-app/45155).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
createAuth0Client({
  useCookiesForTransactions: true
})
```

[useCookiesForTransactions](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/interfaces/Auth0ClientOptions.html#useCookiesForTransactions)

Found a solution here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/issues/671#issuecomment-741902973